# Replacing some parts of an html source code

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

How can I remove whole div's of an HTML source code ?
To remove it I would replace with an empty string but I'm unable to get a pattern which matches. The class name is always given.

For example I need to remove the whole div with class name zzz

```
<div class="zzz"> 
    <b>some html</b>
    (other div's could be inside) 
<div>
```

Hope someone can help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you just need to do `$("div.zzz").remove()`.

Comment: Technically, this would remove it from the DOM, not the source code. But apparently, this is what was intended by the OP.

Comment: this if you are operating client-side, what if you have to do it on server, after getting data from 3rd party service?

Comment: There is no common rule to make it server-side, just have to not display it!

Comment: Doing it server-side would be better but I'm able to use jquery so its fine.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of things it's better to parse the DOM and manipulate parsed object.

Because divs may be nested and you can't control the end of block.

Obviously if you are acting in client-side you can use jquery's

```
$(div.xxxx).remove()
```

Answer (score -1):

Easier than regex is to use jQuery

$('.zzz').remove()

Comment: this if you are operating client-side, what if you have to do it on server, after getting data from 3rd party service?